Get video without embed youtube controller, just get the playback video, using nodejs/reactjs
How to get a raw or videoplayback from youtube and get hd resolutions 720p or more using nodejs and put on reactjs
im using library youtubei.js but the problem is, it can't get hd resolution or more, just 360p,
it is available 1080p but without sound or audio, whenever i try to synchronize between video and audio it get lag because thats stupid idea eat lot of ram, when i try use ffmepg to merge audio and video its too slow and its forbidden in vercel serverless
backend code :
import { Innertube } from 'youtubei.js'

const getVideoStream = async (req, res) => {
  const { videoId } = req.query

  try {
    const yt = await Innertube.create()
    const info = await yt.getInfo(videoId)

    const url = info.streaming_data?.formats[0].decipher(yt.session.player)
    console.info('Playback url:', url)

    const format = info.chooseFormat({ type: 'video', quality: 'best' }) // type video+uadio = 360p not 720p or more
    console.log(format)
    const urlx = format?.decipher(yt.session.player)
    const formats = info.chooseFormat({ type: 'audio', quality: 'best' })
    const urlxx = formats?.decipher(yt.session.player)
    console.info('Playback url:', urlx)
    res.json({ videoUrl: urlx, audioUrl: urlxx })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching video information:', error)
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' })
  }
}

export { getVideoStream }


reactjs code :
import axios from 'axios' and etc...

const VideoPlayer = () => {
  const [videoUrl, setVideoUrl] = useState('')
  const [audioUrl, setAudioUrl] = useState('')
  const { id } = useParams()

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchVideoUrl = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          'http://localhost:5000/get-video-stream',
          {
            params: {
              videoId: id, 
            },
          },
        )

       
        const videoUrl = response.data.videoUrl

        const audioUrl = response.data.audioUrl
        setVideoUrl(videoUrl)
        setAudioUrl(audioUrl)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching video stream:', error)
      }
    }

    fetchVideoUrl()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {videoUrl && (
        <video controls>
          <source src={videoUrl} type="video/mp4" />
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}


to get the hd resolution without any converter or something
